# swf feed from mobile (iOS and android) no image in preview dialogue

Tags: android, ios, facebook, feed

I am publishing a video feed https://developers.facebook.com/docs/feed-gaming/ using this API on mobile content is coming fine on web but in preview on mobile while publishing no image is being displayed. Any way to declare mobile preview image?